# My online dating profile

Tags: riddle

> My hobbies include sailing and collecting ladles.
>   I'm a bit on the heavy side, but people still tell me I'm hot.
>   My spirit animal is a bear,
>   and I never go anywhere without my six best friends.
>   If you know who I am, then you'll know where to look for me.

Where might you find me?

Comment: I really liked this one! Great riddle :)

Comment: This is great! Although it might be slightly more accurate if the third line ended "and you'll never see me anywhere without my six best friends"

Comment: I seriously thought the first line said "... and collecting ladies". Guess the title has an effect on my reading sometimes

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> The North Star (Polaris)

My hobbies include sailing and collecting ladles.

> The North Star is used for navigation and is part of the Little Dipper.

I'm a bit on the heavy side, but people still tell me I'm hot.

> As a star, Polaris is massive and hot.

My spirit animal is a bear, and I never go anywhere without my six best friends.

> Polaris is part of the constellation Ursa Minor (Little Bear), and the Little Dipper (which contains contains 7 stars total.)

If you know who I am, then you'll know where to look for me.

> North

Comment: Nicely done. You did get the wrong ladle, though. This was my first one. Too easy?

Comment: Oops, wrong dipper.  Fixed it now.  It's Ok to have an easy one once in a while.  ;)  Good work.